# Finding Row header value using data in table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have created a data validation list (Assists/2nd Chance Points/Points) and used an XLOOKUP and LARGE function to show values in descending order corresponding to the selection:

[image]

Under the Team column I would like to input the corresponding team names from a dataset in a separate sheet (below) according to the dynamic data of the first sheet (above)

[image]

The outputs would look like this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along the lines :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B4`

```
=INDEX(FILTER(DATASHEET!$A$3:$A$15,
XLOOKUP($C$2,DATASHEET!$B$2:$D$2,DATASHEET!$B$3:$D$15)=C4),
COUNTIF(C$4:C4,C4))
```

---

And fill down for the rest of the cells.

---

Screenshot showing output when it is 2nd Chance Points.

[image]

---

While when its is only Points.

[image]

---

Another alternative approach could be using `TAKE()`, `SORT()`, `HSTACK()` & `FILTER()` Function, here you dont it will extract the whole data i.e. Teams as well as the Homes Points !!

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B4`

```
=TAKE(SORT(HSTACK(DATASHEET!$A$3:$A$15,
FILTER(DATASHEET!$B$3:$D$15,$C$2=DATASHEET!$B$2:$D$2)),2,-1),10)
```

---

Note: In the above formula you don't have to fill right or down, since it will spill all the Top 10 teams !!

---

Further more if you want to add the `Ranks` then just define the above formula within a `LET()` and combine with a `SEQUENCE()` function to get the whole desired output.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `A4`

```
=LET(x,TAKE(SORT(HSTACK(DATASHEET!$A$3:$A$15,
FILTER(DATASHEET!$B$3:$D$15,$C$2=DATASHEET!$B$2:$D$2)),2,-1),10),
HSTACK(SEQUENCE(ROWS(x)),x))
```

---

Added a workbook, feel free to download --> **[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cilItvg4GMjcmIPFv?e=gPP0hR)**

---

Comment: Thanks so much I was struggling to use index with lookup and didn't realise countif would help. The other formulae would be very interesting moving forward.

Comment: @JosephDarton Glad to know that. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

### Rank Teams

```
=LET(Teams,Sheet2!F3:F15,Numbers,Sheet2!G3:G15,bRank,10,
    Data,TAKE(SORT(HSTACK(Teams,Numbers),2,-1),bRank),
HSTACK(SEQUENCE(bRank),Data))
```

- You could define a new name e.g. `Ranks` and use the following in the Name Manager:

```
=LAMBDA(Teams,Numbers,BottomRank,LET(
    Data,TAKE(SORT(HSTACK(Teams,Numbers),2,-1),BottomRank),
HSTACK(SEQUENCE(BottomRank),Data)))
```

- Then you could utilize it anywhere in the workbook with the simple:

```
=Ranks(Sheet2!F3:F15,Sheet2!G3:G15,10)
=Ranks(Sheet2!F3:F15,Sheet2!H3:H15,10)
```